# Delete an item of ListView without reloading in NativeScript, iOS only

Tags: ios, uitableview, nativescript

I have a ListView and I would like to provide users ability to delete any item in it without reloading. So I have made a piece of code that will set the deleted item's `vislibility = "collapsed"`. This works like a charm in Android but not in iOS. It will leave a white space as the item is deleted. Only when I scroll all the way down or up and scroll back, the white space is gone.

Therefore I have tried another way that is to get the native iOS ListView, which is UITableView. And there is a function `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`, so I have done like this:

```
myListView.ios.deleteRowsAtIndexPathsWithRowAnimation([NSIndexPath.indexPathForItemInSection(index, 1)], UITableViewRowAnimation.UITableViewRowAnimationLeft);
```

However, an error appears `Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]`and I don't know what to do next. Actually, I don't really need the animation or fancy thing, I just expect it to work as Android. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A little code will help to understand your problem...
But from the initial looks, I think you need to wrap deleteRowsAtIndexPaths on beginsUpdate and endsUpdate methods call.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26033716/4209778).